# How to convert svg to sld

Tags: java, sld, geotools

I use geotools library for creating my application. Geometries I use need to be represented with style which is defined by sld. I have these styles as a library in svg format and need to convert it to sld. Are there some convertor or software whith which I can make these conversion?

Answer (score 3):

Styled Layer Descriptor XML is not really designed for the task you specify.

You are much better creating SLD XML which links to your SVG files.  For example see the SLD cookbook [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#point-as-graphic) 
This has example SLD code for referring to PNG files; you can simply link to your SVG files instead, for example:

```
<FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
        <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
                <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="smileyface.svg" />
                    <Format>image/svg</Format>
                </ExternalGraphic>
                <Size>32</Size>
            </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>
```

If you need assistance creating the SLD XML you can try using tools such as QGIS (which enables stylings to be exported to SLD, but is not always geoserver compatible) or there is [the SLD editor](http://www.scisys.co.uk/what-we-do/geographic-information-systems/sld-editor.html) (caveat: I have not tested this).